# Eclipse package vs. Eclipse folder, what is the difference?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

Good time of day.

For a long time does not give rest to the question that periodically arises when working on projects.

What is the difference between Eclipse package and Eclipse folder.

I understand that structurally there is no difference in the directory tree. But Eclipse also somehow discerns in the Package Explorer, that's packages, they need to display another icon, you can show them in Flat form, they can lead the way to shorter species, unlike folders, which are displayed with another icon and display all of the consistent directory structure.

How does Eclipse understand that there is a difference between them? Where does it store settings to understand the difference? Is it possible to configure the package value manually somewhere in the config files or in Eclipse settings?

The issue arose after migrating the project from another IDE, and after migrating the part of the project directories located in the test directory did not get the package status, which led to an error in the classes indicating the package. I. e. all structure of directories corresponds to structure of the necessary packages, but, without a mark that these directories are packages classes give out errors.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Sorry, text was translated by machine :).

P.P.S. I asked the same question in the russian part of stackoverflow, but didn't get the answer, Does anybody know the answer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the Build Path: whatever folder is under the build path is a JAVA package.

If your build path is `/src/main/java` then src, main, java are folders.
If inside `/src/main/java`, your app is structured like this com/foo/bar/Main.java, then com, foo and bar are packages.

You can see and edit your build path by `Right Click on your project > Properties > Java Build Path`

Eclipse IDE stores the build path in a file called .classpath. This file is specific to Eclipse IDE; there is one at the root of each Java project. You may not see it from the Project/Package Explorer because Eclipse IDE filters it out by default but you'll see from your file browser.

Usually it looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

As you can see, the src/ directory is within the classpath which means that every folder under it will be a package.

Comment: Thank you :).
I used it, but didn't understand what I was doing :).

Comment: I completed my answer with the information brought by echebbi. Have fun configuring Eclipse!